# How do you store a JSON object as a function parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive to populate a chart using the AmCharts API. The function that is currently being used lists out the data that is populating the form in JSON format as a parameter in the function. I want to be able to store this as a variable so I can have a separate file for the JSON. I know you probably have to use $http to get the json, but I am unsure how you would connect this to the directive.

```
var myapp = angular.module('tmn_portfolio', []);

myapp.directive('loadPortfolio',
 function () {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace:true,

   template: '<div id="chartdiv" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var chart = false;

        var initChart = function() {
          if (chart) chart.destroy();
          var config = scope.config || {};
           chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", I WANT THIS TO BE A VARIABLE TO JSON FILE);

        };
        initChart();

 }//end watch           
  }
}) ;
```

Comment: but from where you want to set your variable value ?

Comment: a JSON file... like data.json

Comment: no I mean you have the url of the JSON file in your scope ?

Comment: no i need to know how to attach it to scope and then reference it in the next function

Comment: you can inherit your scope by setting scope:true , then in your directive write in inherited scope your value , and read it from other side

Comment: what would "the other side" look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60542/discussion-between-narek-mamikonyan-and-philip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution than `scope: true` would be to pass the data to the directive in an attribute.  The markup will look like this:

```
<load-portfolio my-data="jsonData" ></load-portfolio>
```

That element will be replaced by your template.  In the directive:

```
myapp.directive('loadPortfolio',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace:true,
            scope: {
                myData: '='
            },
            template: '<div id="chartdiv" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var chart = false;
                var initChart = function() {
                    if (chart) chart.destroy();
                    var config = scope.config || {};
                    chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", scope.myData);
                };
                initChart();
            }//end watch           
        }
    });
```

The equals sign is a two way binding between the property `myData` on the directive scope, and the property `jsonData` on the scope of your controller (the "model" in angular terms).  Any time the data changes in the controller, it will also change in the directive, and your UI will update to reflect that.

Now you just have to get the json data, right?  You are right, you should probably use $http to do this, and what that will look like will depend on your specific implementation, but the important part is that once you populate `jsonData`, your directive will be updated to reflect that.  I typically initialize models that will be populated asynchronously in my controller. A very simple version might look something like this:

```
myapp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.jsonData = {};  // or '' - depending on whether you actually want the JSON string here.

    $http({
        url: '/data.json',
        method: 'GET'
    }).
    then(function(r) {
        $scope.jsonData = r.data;
    });
}]);
```

I think that to do it properly you should look into routing and the `resolve` property of routes which allows you to retrieve the data before your controller loads, and pass it as an argument to the controller, but that is really up to you.

Update:  Like the other answer, I do recommend using a factory/service for calls to your server or API, instead of using $http directly in the controller like in my example.  Just trying to keep it simple here.  Angular code is more fun when well-organized.

Comment: the ultimate goal is to query a json from the etrade APi, so then I should probably use factory?

Comment: yes I do like this answer for simplicity and easy to understand, but how would you reccomend if i was parsing an external API like a JSON provided from Google Analytics API or Etrade API?

Comment: Also wouldn't it be Restrict: "A"

Comment: Restrict 'E' is correct for the usage in my answer.  Restrict 'A' means that you can only use the directive as an attribute: `<div load-portfolio ></div>`.

Comment: Just parse the data however you want to in the `then` callback.  JSON parse is built-in to modern browsers.

Comment: i guess i meant would you just put the external link in $http?

Comment: You are going to have some complications with that do to restrictions on cross-domain scripting.  Common solutions would be to wrap those calls to the remote API into your own API, or to use jsonp.  [Read the manual.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

You need a factory or service to first request your JSON file and store it as a variable:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);


app.factory('data', function($http) { 
var data = {
    async: function() {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      var promise = $http.get('file.json').then(function (response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return data;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( data,$scope) {
  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
  data.async().then(function(d) {
    $scope.jsonData = d; ;
  });

});
```

Comment: what does your config service do?

Comment: It is required for cross-origin requests within AngularJS. Without it your AngularJS AJAX requests won't function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: and then i would just plug in $scope.jsonData as a parameter in makeChart() ?